# Win32 application not finding icon for window

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I created a icon as a resource

[image: Icon in solution explorer]

I checked explorer and it works just fine, my exe now has that icon

Next, I used hIcon to set the icon of my window but it says that IDI_ICON1 is undefined
[image]

Code:

```
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
```

Is there any idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Maybe you did not include the header for the resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbolic constants for resource identifiers (such as `IDI_ICON1`) are usually stored in a separate header file called *Resource.h* by default. This allows both the resource script (.rc file) as well as source code to access the same symbols.

To use the constants in source code you need to introduce them through an `#include` directive. Otherwise the compiler is unable to find them, as the error messages indicates.